# Dynamic JsonIgnore for properties within a list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using the [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library. I have some JSON which looks like this:

```
"Templates": [
    {
        "Name": "Default Fields 1",
        "Fields": [16, 10, 0, 4, 5, 11, 12, 7, 15, 17, 9, 25, 3],
        "Formats": [
            "string", "datetime", "LeftZeroPaddedString13", "2dp", "2dp", "2dp", "2dp", "int", "int",
            "string", "int", "int", "int", "int"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Name": "Default Fields 2",
        "Fields": [3, 25, 9, 17, 15, 7, 12, 11, 5, 4, 0, 10, 16],
        "Formats": [
            "int", "int", "int", "int", "string", "int", "int", "2dp", "2dp", "2dp", "2dp", "LeftZeroPaddedString13",
            "datetime", "string"
        ]
    }]
```

And I am deserializing it to the `Templates` property within the following class:

```
public class Options
{
    public List<FieldTemplate> Templates { get; set; }
}
public class FieldTemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Fields { get; set; }
    public List<string> Formats { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine, but under some circumstances (not always) I want to prevent the `Fields` and `Formats` properties from being included when I serialize the object again (though I do want to keep the `Name` property in the serialized output). I have thought about using `ShouldSerializeFields()` and `ShouldSerializeFormats()` within `FieldTemplate` and then looping through the object to set a boolean property which each of these methods can read, but it doesn't seem elegant. Is there a better way? For example, I could set boolean properties in `Options` which `FieldTemplate` could then use. I don't know how to do that though, or even if its possible.

Comment: You can use a custom contract resolver to do this.  See Andrew Whitaker's answer in [Dynamic json serialization filtering via reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28606326/10263); looks like that should work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @BrianRogers. In the end I took Vitaliy's advice and used a static class as this suits my needs better. I'll post an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a static class with a switch for each property i wanted to dynamically show/hide:

```
public class FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches
{
    public static bool Fields = true;
    public static bool Formats = true;
}

public class Options
{
    public List<FieldTemplate> Templates { get; set; }
}

public class FieldTemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> Fields { get; set; }
    public List<string> Formats { get; set; }

    // instructions to Json.NET
    public bool ShouldSerializeFields()
    {
        return FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches.Fields;
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeFormats()
    {
        return FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches.Formats;
    }
}
```

Then from elsewhere I can enable/disable these properties:

```
if (condition)
{
    FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches.Fields = true;
    FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches.Formats = false;
}
else
{
    FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches.Fields = false;
    FieldTemplate_JSONSerialization_Switches.Formats = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is similar question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681538/json-net-use-jsonignoreattribute-only-on-serialization-but-not-when-deserialz).

Json.Net documentation about [ConditionalProperties](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

**Edit**
To not iterate over collection create static object and check it's properties inside ShouldSerializeXYZ().

Comment: That's just the `ShouldSerializeXYZ()` that I mentioned in my question. The problem I am having is more about how to conditionally trigger `ShouldSerializeXYZ()` when its within an object in a list.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Then create static object and check it's properties inside ShouldSerializeXYZ() :)